# Strange behavior of left arrow key in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

When I press the left arrow to return to column A - it will not stop at column A but will continue to wrap around to the end (column XEP or something huge like that). How do I make it stop when it gets to A?

Thank you I understand the home key. Let me restate my question. For example I am at cell number BH21 and for what I'm working on I need to use the left scroll button to move quickly along the row until I reach A column. My problem is that moving that quickly the left arrow button doesn't stop when it reaches A column but just keeps going and wraps around to the very end column XEP21 or whatever the end is. I was already using the spreadsheet with no problem then after modifying a few things this occurred.

Comment: What cells exactly are selected before and after you press left arrow?

Comment: [Once somebody said to me, “I’m trying to pound nails into this wood shelf.  Should I use an old shoe or a glass bottle?”](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx)  The answer is, “Neither, use a hammer.”  Similarly, if you want to get from cell QU42 to cell A42 by pressing left arrow 462 times instead of pressing the Home key once, it behooves you to explain why you want to do it that way.

Comment: Do you know what “few things” you modified between when left arrow was working normally and when it started exhibiting this unusual behavior?

Comment: Scott - hahaha do I really have to explain - hahaha it's actually my husband that uses the spreadsheet I only do the modifications for him. As to why he likes to move it by using the left arrow - your guess is as good as mine. I'm just trying to make things right in his world. ;) As for the modifications well there were a lot of them - formulas, moving cells, removing rows etc., adding rows -  so hard to determine what would have caused the problem.

Comment: As long as we’re joking around, here’s a classic: A man walks into his doctor’s office and says, “Doctor, it hurts when I do this,” (and illustrates some motion).  The doctor replies, “Well, then, don’t do that.”

Comment: But seriously, when you respond to comments (in a new comment), it’s conventional to mention the author’s name, preceded by a “@” symbol, as in “@Scott”.  That way he gets notified.  You can mention multiple names, as in “@person1, @person2”, but there is a limit of two or three.  See the **Replying in comments** paragraphs of [the **Comment formatting** section](http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) of the Markdown Editing Help page.  I just found your “hahaha” response above because I manually came back to this question to check whether there had been any activity.

Comment: @Scott -Oh thanks  am new to all of this so appreciate the lesson.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not 100% sure what you want to learn.  If you want to know how to get to Column A in the current row, try just pressing <kbd>Home</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that certain calls are unlocked (so you can edit them), but when the author protected the sheet, they chose (only) "*Select unlocked cells*", which prevents the end-user from clicking on locked cells, and turns on that arrow-key wrapping you are asking about.

If you unprotect the document and then protect it again, only selecting **both** "*Select locked cells*" and "*Select unlocked cells*", then the end user can access locked cells (just not change them), and the arrow-keys will work like they normally do (no wrapping).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and realized it only happened when I had my sheet protected and cells locked.

The solution is this:

Go to Review>Unprotect Sheet

Then right click the sheet tab at the bottom of the screen and choose View Code

You'll get a screen that has two panels on the left. On the bottom panel, in "Enable Selection" choose "0 - xlNoRestriction"

Hit the save button and close this screen

Re-protect your sheet

This will allow any cell to be selected even if it is locked (but you will get an error message if you try to edit a locked cell)

Hope this helps!